# Unable to read some registry keys under the same branch in Windows 2008 (32-bit)

Tags: winapi, registry, windows-server-2008

I am using the following code to read the value of a registry key. I am able to successfully read the value of the key when `szValueName=L"Background"` under the branch `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"`.

However when i try to read the value when `szValueName=L"DefaultDomainName"` under the same branch, `RegOpenKeyEx()` returns 0(ERROR_SUCCESS) and `RegQueryValueEx()` returns 2(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). Surprisingly am able to read both values from the commandline using REG QUERY command.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    wchar_t* szValueName;
    wchar_t* KeyName;
    HKEY hKey;
    DWORD dwBufLen;
    LONG lret;
    DWORD* reservedNULL = NULL;
    DWORD reservedZero = 0;

    szValueName = L"DefaultDomainName"; 
    KeyName = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon";
    lret = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KeyName, reservedZero, KEY_READ, &hKey);
    if (lret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        dwBufLen = MAX_PATH;
        lret = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, szValueName, reservedNULL, NULL, (BYTE*)buffer, &dwBufLen);
        if (lret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
           wcout << buffer << endl;
        } // end if successfull value read
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    } // end if successfule key open

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, is your app 32-bit or is it the OS that is 32-bit?

Comment: @Anders the OS is 32 bit

Comment: The Registry API does not lie. If `RegQueryValueEx()` says a value doesn't exist then it really doesn't exist. For instance, on my machine, there is no `DefaultDomainName` value in that `Winlogon` key under 64bit, but there is under WOW64). So double check your key path, the spelling of the value name, that the value really does exist, etc.

Comment: FYI, `RegQueryValueEx()` does not guarantee that your `buffer` will be null-terminated, but your use of `wcout << buffer` assumes it does. Use `wcout.write(buffer, dwBufLen)` (decrementing `dwBufLen` first if a null terminator actually is present), or else use `RegGetValue()` instead.

Comment: `DefaultDomainName` won't be present by default in all workstations. Have you checked that it actually exists in that location?